# Getting an unexpected token error (expecting ";") in my react native screen?

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error in my react native screen file:

```
SyntaxError in /MyFile.js: Unexpected token, expected ; (5:10)
```

I've been staring at it for quit a while trying to figure out what is wrong, but I am new to React.

Here is MyFile.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const LogInScreen = () => {
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Login</Text>
      </View>
      );
  };

};

export default LogInScreen
```

I double checked the ES6 syntax, and my arrow function appears correct.  I have tried it with parentheses instead of braces, and parentheses around the braces just to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the render since it's a const.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const LogInScreen = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Login</Text>
      </View>
      );

};

export default LogInScreen
```

If you want to use render, change your code to this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class LogInScreen extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Login</Text>
      </View>
      );
  };

};

export default LogInScreen
```